# Disable secret caller id

Tags: ubuntu-touch

My network uses secret caller id by default.
With my previous phones, there were settings to explicitly choose *not* to use secret caller id.
How would I do the same on a ubuntu phone?

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the Ubuntu phone doesn't have such a setting at the moment. When I want that the other see my phone number than I type *31# at front at the number, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID#Enabling (that is only a work around but helpful)

If this work for you is depending on your provider and the country in which you were living.